# C++ Selection Sort not Sorting Some Values of an Array

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to sort an array of integers using a selection sort algorithm, but some of the numbers aren't sorting. Below is the isolated section of my code that does the sorting and the output. Any suggestions?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int smallestIndex;
    int temp;
    
    int X[13] = {1, 19, 2, 18, 4, 12, 7, 8, 10, 3, 11, 17, 9};
    
    for (int Index = 0; Index < 12; Index++) {
        smallestIndex = Index;
        for (int minIndex = Index+1; minIndex < 13; minIndex++) {
            if (X[minIndex] < X[smallestIndex]) {
                smallestIndex=minIndex;
            }
            if (smallestIndex != Index) {
                temp = X[Index];
                X[Index] = X[smallestIndex];
                X[smallestIndex] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        cout << X[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

output:

```
1                                                                  
2                                                                  
4                                                                  
7                                                                  
9                                                                  
3                                                                  
10                                                                 
8                                                                  
11                                                                 
12                                                                 
17                                                                 
18                                                                 
19
```

Comment: The programmer's secret weapon is the debugger. With a debugger you can run the program on your terms and watch what the program does as it does it. Step through the program and monitor the variables and flow of code. As soon as you catch the program doing something unexpected, you've found a bug. Finding the solution may take a bit more work, but finding the problem is a very important step in solving the problem.

Comment: You second `if`-statement doesn't want to be inside the nested loop.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way to do this by using the `swap()` function, and using two more functions called, `void selectionSort()` and `void printArray()` to make the code look cleaner.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <algorithm>

  
void swap(int *xp, int *yp)  
{  
    int temp = *xp;  
    *xp = *yp;  
    *yp = temp;  
}  
  
void selectionSort(int arr[], int n)  
{  
    int i, j, min_idx;  
  
    // One by one move boundary of unsorted subarray  
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)  
    {  
        // Find the minimum element in unsorted array  
        min_idx = i;  
        for (j = i+1; j < n; j++)  
        if (arr[j] < arr[min_idx])  
            min_idx = j;  
  
       
        swap(&arr[min_idx], &arr[i]);  
    }  
}  
  

void printArray(int arr[], int size)  
{  
    int i;  
    for (i=0; i < size; i++)  
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";  
    std::cout << std::endl;  
}  
  
 
int main()  
{  
    int arr[] = {1, 19, 2, 18, 4, 12, 7, 8, 10, 3, 11, 17, 9}; 
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);  
    selectionSort(arr, n);  
    std::cout << "The sorted array is: \n";  
    printArray(arr, n);  
    return 0;  
}
```

Output:

```
The sorted array is: 
1 2 3 4 7 8 9 10 11 12 17 18 19
```

Another way you could do this is by just strictly using `std::swap` without the use of `pointers`. Make sure to include the `#include<algorithm>` header file for `std::swap`. You will also need to include `#include <iterator>` for `std::size`.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
 
int main()
{
     int arr[] = {1, 19, 2, 18, 4, 12, 7, 8, 10, 3, 11, 17, 9}; 
    constexpr int length{ static_cast<int>(std::size(arr)) };
    //constexpr means that value of a variable can appear in a constant expression.
 
    // Step through each element of the array
    
    for (int startIndex{ 0 }; startIndex < length - 1; ++startIndex)
    {
        
        int smallestIndex{ startIndex };
 
        // Then look for a smaller element in the rest of the array
        for (int currentIndex{ startIndex + 1 }; currentIndex < length; ++currentIndex)
        {
            if (arr[currentIndex] < arr[smallestIndex])
            
                smallestIndex = currentIndex;
        }
 
        
                // swap our start element with our smallest element 
        std::swap(arr[startIndex], arr[smallestIndex]);
    }
 
    // Now that the whole array is sorted, print it.
    for (int index{ 0 }; index < length; ++index)
        std::cout << arr[index] << ' ';
 
    std::cout << '\n';
 
    return 0;
}
```

You could also just use `std::sort` instead. It is in the header file `#include<algorithm>` which just sorts in ascending order by default. You will also need the header file `#include <iterator>` for `std::size`

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator> 
 
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1, 19, 2, 18, 4, 12, 7, 8, 10, 3, 11, 17, 9}; 
 
    std::sort(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
 
    for (int i{ 0 }; i < static_cast<int>(std::size(arr)); ++i)
        std::cout << array[i] << ' ';
 
    std::cout << '\n';
 
    return 0;
}
```